# How do I get ride of the gap in table footnote generated by kable in r markdown?

Tags: r-markdown, kable

As you can see from the pic below. There is a gap between the `note` and the context.

[image]

The code I used is below. Any ideas to get rid of the gap?

```
kable(summarize(df.sum, group = "Experiment", test = T, digits = 1, show.NAs = F),
             row.names = F, caption = 'Summary Statistics for Treated and Control Groups',
             booktabs = T) %>% kable_styling(latex_options = c('striped', 'hold_position')) %>%
  footnote(general = 'DM8OZ indicates the daily max 8-hour ozone concentration; 
Daily_PM2.5 is the daily average of PM2.5; Tavg is the daily average temperature; 
Prcp is the daily accumulated precipitation. The last column in the table represents the testing results of null 
hypotheses that the treated and control groups are not statistically different. ',
footnote_as_chunk = T, threeparttable = T, fixed_small_size = T)
```

Comment: Hey Yabin Da, have you found a solution to the problem? I am experiencing the same issue and would appreciate if you could post an update if you have solved the problem. Cheers!

Comment: @cthulhukk Unfortunately, I was unable to fix the problem within the `ktable` function. I ended up creating the table completely in LaTex, in which I used the `tablenote` function.